# Integration - Sums and Difference of Areas

Tags: integration

7. Find the area enclosed between the curves $y = (x - 1)^2$ and $y=(x+1)^2$

I Understand the graphing and that they intersect at $(0,1)$. However once I solve, I keep getting $\frac{16}{3}$ but the answer where as the textbook says the answer is $\frac{2}{3}$ ??

Comment: Are you sure you've copied the question down right? Those two curves don't enclose an area by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a poorly worded question to me (as you have specified it). It looks more like they want the area under the curve of the two graphs. As you said, the intersection of the two curves is at $(0,1)$ and we are integrating over $D \in (-1, 1)$ so we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{D} f(x) dx &= \int_{-1}^{0} (x + 1)^{2} dx + \int_{0}^{1} (x - 1)^{2} dx \\
&= \frac{(x + 1)^{3}}{3} \biggr \vert_{-1}^{0} + \frac{(x - 1)^{3}}{3} \biggr \vert_{0}^{1} \\
&= \frac{1}{3} - \bigg( \frac{-1}{3} \bigg) \\
&= \frac{2}{3}
\end{align}$$

Alternatively, notice that the function $f(x) = (x + 1)^{2} + (x - 1)^{2}$ is even, hence

$$\begin{align}
\int_{D} f(x) dx &= \int_{-1}^{1} (x + 1)^{2} + (x - 1)^{2} dx \\
&= 2 \int_{-1}^{0} (x + 1)^{2} dx \\
&= 2 \bigg[ \frac{(x + 1)^{3}}{3} \bigg ]_{-1}^{0} \\
&= 2 \bigg( \frac{1}{3} \bigg) \\
&= \frac{2}{3}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

As charlotte suggests, those two curves don't enclose an area by themselves.

They do intersect at $(0,1)$, but that's the only place.

Try using the $x$ axis as another boundary and try the integral again.  I think that's the piece you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

We see that :
$$y_1(x)=y_2(-x)$$
Therefore the two curves are symmetric about $Y$. We need only integrate $y_1(x)$ from $0$ to $1$ where it meets $X$.
$$\left.\int_0^1(x-1)^2 \, dx=(1/3)(x-1)^3\right|_0^1=(1/3)$$
Double it to get $I=2/3$.